# Javascript homework. Making a yearly calendar

Tags: javascript

I am trying to print a yearly calendar on one page using JS. This specifically seems to be the function giving me issues. Let me know if you could point me in the right direction, or if I can provide more info. Thanks

```
function yearly(calDate)    {
    if (calDate == null) calendarDay = new Date();
    else calendarDay = new Date(calDate)

    var currentTime = calendarDay.getTime();
    var thisYear = calendarDay.getFullYear();

    <table id='yearly_table'><tr>
        <th id='yearly_title' colspan='4'>
        thisYear;
    </th>
    </tr>
    var monthNum=-1;

    for (var i=1;i<=3;i++)  {
        document.write("<tr>");
    for (var j=1;j<=4;j++) {
        monthNum=monthNum++;
        calendarDay.setDate(1);
        calendarDay.setMonth(monthNum);
        writeMonthCell(calendarDay, currentTime);
    }
    <"</tr>">
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the exact problem you are encountering? You should try to ask a clear question. "Complete my homework" is not, by itself, a good question.

Comment: I wrote the function, I am not asking you to do it for me at all, I am trying to figure out why it hits an error at <table and will not print the calendar. sorry if I wasn't clear, just stuck

Comment: You should have mentioned "compilation error in <table line". That would have been a concrete problem. @Jeroen points you in the right direction.

Comment: I understand, I do apologize, I am pretty new at this. I appreciate both of you looking into it for me though. Thanks, I will learn sooner or later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't put html into a javascript function like that. Javascript can only contain javascript statements, no html tags. The browser will try to execute your html as being javascript statements and won't recognise any of it.

You need to insert it into the DOM. Use methods like getElementById, createElement and appendChild. [More info here](http://www.impressivewebs.com/10-essential-dom-methods-techniques-for-practical-javascript/)

For example, to write some text to an element you do this:

```
// get the element using it's ID
var element = document.getElementById("myElementId");

// create a child element
var newElement = document.createTextNode("This is my text");

// write some text into it
element.appendChild(newElement);
```

[You can see the example run here](http://jsfiddle.net/NACzs/)

Comment: I'm trying to call the script in an html page, so the <table... code should all be in the html file? Thats actually exactly where the error occurs. My JS book isn't very clear on some things.

Comment: I'll put more clarification in my answer

Comment: HEY!! I moved it to the html file and cleaned up a few syntax errors from the JS file I had and it is now printing the calendar!! thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: ALthough I have a new problem, all of the month titles are printing as december... I guess I will work on that. I appreciate you pointing me in the right direction

Comment: Nevermind, actually figured that out as well, I had monthNum=monthNum++ instead of monthNum=monthNum+1. apparently I have a bit to learn about increments

Comment: To increment you only do this: monthNum++; (that is shorthand for monthNum = monthNum + 1;)

Comment: Ahh, so I didnt need monthNum=monthNum++ I ONLY needed to write monthNum++ ? I guess that makes sense. I do have one more question if you don't mind. Could I ask you a quick question about the HTML?

Comment: Yes exactly. If you have another question you should post it as a new question. But if it's a small detail you can go ahead

Comment: well, my calendar is printing correctly but the footer of the page seems to be printing above the calendar instead of below it, should I go ahead and post a new question? I feel like it is a silly mistake but I don't see it

Comment: That's a new question, ask it and post your html code so we can see what's going wrong

Comment: if you could take a look please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12384293/html-page-printing-incorrectly

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function yearly(calDate) {
    if (calDate == null) {
    var calendarDay = new Date();
    } else { 
      var calendarDay = new Date(calDate);
      }

var currentTime = calendarDay.getTime();
var thisYear = calendarDay.getFullYear();
document.write("<table id='yearly_table'><tr>");
document.write("<th id='yearly_title' colspan='4'>");
document.write(thisYear);
document.write("</th></tr>");
var monthNum = calendarDay.getMonth();
var monthNum = -1;

for (var i=0; i<=2; i++) {
  document.write("<tr>");
    for (var j=0; j<=3; j++) {
     monthNum++;
     calendarDay.setDate(1);
     calendarDay.setMonth(monthNum);
     writeMonthCell(calendarDay, currentTime);
     }
    document.write("</tr>");
  }
 document.write("</table>");   
}
```