# HTML page printing incorrectly

Tags: html

I am printing a javascript calendar in the middle of this page, for some reason when I run this code the Address block prints above the table where the calendar prints. I need the calendar to print above the address bar. Thanks in advance for any help

```
<body>
    <div id="head">
        <img style="float: right; border: 1px solid orange" src="photo.jpg" alt="" />
        <img src="ccc.jpg" alt="Chamberlain Civic Center" />
    </div>

   <div id="links">
       <table><tr>
           <td><a href="#">Home</a></td><td><a href="#">Tickets</a></td>
           <td><a href="#">Events</a></td><td><a href="#">Directions</a></td>
           <td><a href="#">Hours</a></td><td><a href="#">Calendar</a></td>
           <td><a href="#">Tour</a></td><td><a href="#">Contact Us</a></td>
       </tr></table>
   </div>

   <div id="main">
       <h1>Yearly Calendar</h1>
       <table id='yearly_table'>
       <tr>
           <th id='yearly_title' colspan='4'></th>
       </tr>
       <script type="text/javascript">
           yearly();
       </script>
   </div>

   <address>
   The Chamberlain Civic Center &nbsp;&#183;&nbsp;
   2011 Canyon Drive &nbsp;&#183;&nbsp;
   Chamberlain, SD 57325 &nbsp;&#183;&nbsp;
   (800) 555-8741
   </address>

</body>
```

Comment: Put the address tag inside a div tag and see what the result is?

Comment: I could be doing it wrong, but if I put <div> above address and </div> below address it doesn't seem to move. This portion of the project was even written for us in the book, not sure why it's not working as intended.

Comment: Looks like you didn't close the table tag, put this below the `</script>` line: `</table>`

Comment: That did it. I really do appreciate all of your help sir. Wish I could return the favor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you didn't close the table tag, put this below the `</script>` line: `</table>`

Comment: You're welcome, always keep your eyes open for incomplete tags :) Please click the 'V' on the left of this answer to accept it if this answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding address to div tag. Like this.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="head">
      <img style="float: right; border: 1px solid orange" src="photo.jpg" alt="" />
      <img src="ccc.jpg" alt="Chamberlain Civic Center" />
  </div>

  <div id="links">
  <table>
    <tr>
     <td><a href="#">Home</a></td><td><a href="#">Tickets</a></td>
     <td><a href="#">Events</a></td><td><a href="#">Directions</a></td>
     <td><a href="#">Hours</a></td><td><a href="#">Calendar</a></td>
     <td><a href="#">Tour</a></td><td><a href="#">Contact Us</a></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </div>

  <div id="main">
   <h1>Yearly Calendar</h1>
        <table id='yearly_table'><tr>
        <th id='yearly_title' colspan='4'>

    </th>
    </tr>
   <script type="text/javascript">
  yearly();
  </script>
   </div>

  <div>
  <address>
  The Chamberlain Civic Center &nbsp;&#183;&nbsp;
  2011 Canyon Drive &nbsp;&#183;&nbsp;
  Chamberlain, SD 57325 &nbsp;&#183;&nbsp;
  (800) 555-8741
  </address>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: and closing the table worked beautifully. Thanks to both of you.